# How to link Microsoft Access Database file with HTML

Tags: html, ms-access

I created a table in Microsoft Access Database and I wanted to use this database in the website I built with HTML. The problem is that I don't know how to link the database file to my website (or to the form inside the body of the HTML file, I actually don't even know how it works...). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly i don't know much about Microsoft Access Database . I assume it is like other databases.

But, if you would like information that you made within a database to be shown in html, it will take much more than just html.  There are a few paths you can take depending on what you want to accomplish.

The first thing is that your Database (hereby named "DB") needs to be accessible online (where your web page would live). Unless Microsoft Access Database is a "Cloud based" DB.

I use Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio (MSSM) for by DB needs, but MongoDB is a cloud based solution.

With MSSM you can use Amazon Web Services to create a webserver that runs MSSM and is accessible via the cloud.

The second thing to do would be to be able to get information from your DB to your webpage.  There may be an easier solution, which I will recommend. I use C# to do this, but I know it can also be done with Ruby, and NodeJS.  Within either of those languages, you will need an Object Relational Mapper (ORM), to read the info from your DB and then Create,Read,Update or Delete (CRUD) to and from your DB. An example of an ORM is EntityFrameWork or Nhibernate.

But there is a different way.  If you are ok with not using a DB, you can use XML or JSON files much the same way as a DB. Which is what I did. 
  [My github repo](https://github.com/aaronlilly/ServerlessBrix) 
 [Check out my non-db solution](https://aaronlilly.github.io/ServerlessBrix/Lego2.html) 

The short version is that all of your info in your DB can be represented using .JSON files.You can then use Javascript (or Jquery) to view and display (not update) the info.

if you need help with this, leave a way to contact you, it is too much to put here.

Answer (score 0):

How you do this will depend on your web development tools.

And it also depends on your web hosting company.

Remember, a web server is just a computer. It not really much different of a computer then your desktop.

And on your desktop, if you want to use say word, then you need word installed.

And on your web server, if you want to write code say in python, or asp.net, then your web site computer has to support that type of programming language.

So a web site that connects to a database will mean that you have to write some code in the web programming system of your choice. (However, that choice is limited to the tools available on that web site just like if word or say FoxPro, or Access is installed on your desktop computer.

So quite a few web hosting companies do support using an Access database. Note that this is ONLY the data part they support (so just the tables, not VBA code or forms/reports).

So, you have to either:

Pick some web programming languages you like or are familiar with, and then

Choose a web hosting provider that supports the programming language(s) you want or like to use.

Or, check your current web hosting provider and learn the tools and programming language(s) that they currently support.

For example, a really common development stack (set of tools) is called LAMP.

Lamp = Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP.

So, if they support LAMP, then the server is a Linux server, the web server system is Apache, and the database is MySQL, and the programming language is PHP.

Keep in mind that Access does not work on the LAMP stack. (It is not a windows server, and just like you can’t install Access on an Apple Mac, you can’t install the Access data drivers on a LAMP server.

However, in most cases you don’t really care, because your code going to be the same if you pull table data from SQL server, MySQL server, or a Access database. In all 3 cases, you going to write some SQL queries against that database (to be fair, the SQL flavors do vary a bit. So Access SQL is mostly the same as SQL server, but there are minor differences). Since your code can ONLY use the tables, then you tend to not care much if the tables are in Access or MySQL. Your SQL queries you write will be VERY similar no matter what database you use to hold the tables.

If your web hosting provider supports and uses asp.net, then that web server is a Microsoft server. These are the ones that support using Access databases. And asp.net programming languages can be c# or vb.net.  VB.net is nice, since it reads and you can code very much like VBA code (the syntax is very similar). And web pages (web forms) have event models somewhat similar to what you use on the Access desktop.

So, HTML alone is not sufficient for writing code. HTML can lay out some text on a web page, but it does not allow you to write code with SQL and loops and everything you come to expect with a programming language like we have say in Access (VBA).

So what kind of web server is hosting your web pages will determine what programming languages are installed and can be used on the web computer.

Apache is a common web server. That web server can dish out HTML pages, but ALSO allow you to write code for the web page. It is the coding part that allows you to execute SQL against the database to return data, and shove it into the HTML page that you have created.

If you using an IBM server, then the web server is WebSphere.

And if you using ASP.net, then the web server is IIS (internet information services).

So there is “many” different kinds of web servers. While any of these web servers (the server that dishes out web pages to users) allow HTML, they all use different programming languages.

Also, because the database used (Access, MySQL, SQL server etc.) only holds the tables, so at the end of the day, it tends to not be a big deal if you  use Access to hold some tables, or say using MySQL database to hold the tables.

However, say if you have experience with SQL server from Microsoft, and are comfortable with that system, then it makes sense to choose a web server (hosting provider) that supports SQL server, since you will be familiar with that database server more than say using MySQL or Oracle databases.

So, how you get your data into the HTML page will depend on what web programming language your web hosting provider supports.

So you either choose the tools your current web hosting provider supports, or you pick the web programming tools and languages you like, and find a web hosting provider that supports those programming languages.

So this is not different then say choosing Access. If you choose and like Access, then you can’t run your software on an Apple Mac.

And of course if you use some Mac programming language, then you can’t run that software on windows.

So, how this works is exactly the same for when you choose a web server. That web server will run windows software, or say often Linux software. So you have use and write code that the given web hosting system you are using supports.

A web server is just a computer with software installed. If you want to write some code to pull the data, then you write that code in some programming language that is installed and supporting on the web server system you are using.

So, web sites that dish out data are NOT just HTML but also will have code written to send SQL to the database, and pull that data into the web page. What programing you choose is quite much like what kind of ice cream you like. (You have lots of choices here).

So web hosting systems support HTML, but EVEN what features of HTML are supported will vary from hosting provider to provider.